# Docker SocketIO not found (Python)

Tags: docker, socket.io, python-socketio

When running my [Python-SocketIO](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) app normally, the SocketIO connection to the frontend works fine. In a docker container, it can't be connected to.

Output from Docker container:

```
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ========

(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[A similar problem](https://github.com/PokemonGoF/PokemonGo-Bot/issues/5045) was brought up for the standard SocketIO but Python-SocketIO doesn't mention a `config.json` file, therefore I didn't include one to any capacity. I also don't believe it matters because the program's output already depicts `0.0.0.0:8080` as opposed to `127.0.0.1:8080`

My run configuration(s):  -> Have tried all

```
docker run --rm -d <CONTAINER_ID>
docker run --rm -d --network host <CONTAINER_ID>
docker run --rm -d --network host <CONTAINER_ID> -p 0.0.0.0:8080/tcp
```

**8/19/20 NOTE:** Connection to docker container is made via the [Client API](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/).

Comment: How are you trying to connect to it?  Do you have any `docker run -p` options, or is what you show all of it?

Comment: What I've included is all of it (except the front-end, but the connection works for when the application is not in a Docker container. @DavidMaze

Comment: I think @DavidMaze was trying to know how you were trying to connect to your frontend when saying `In a docker container, it can't be connected to`. Are you using a browser? Curl? Which URL or IP are you trying to join your Dockerized frontend with?

Comment: I'm connecting via the SocketIO JS Client library. I'm running the JS Client on `localhost:3000` and attempting to connect to the container on `localhost:8080` @PierreB.

Comment: could you please add dockerfile in question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the `<CONTAINER_ID>` in your run commands is a custom image tag? Containers and images are different things.

The problem looks to be that you aren't using the correct form for the `-p`/`--publish` argument to the run command. In the simplest form, you would use `{host-port}:{container-port}`, e.g. `8080:8080`. You can optionally be explicit that the port should be on all interfaces with `0.0.0.0:8080:8080`, or restrict to host loopback with `127.0.0.1:8080:8080`. Add on the `/tcp` to the end to restrict to only TCP packets. You can make the container port 8080 exposed on a random dynamic port with `0.0.0.0::8080` (note the extra colon!), or instead use `-P`/`--publish-all` to do that with all exposed ports on the container.

It sounds like you want to use something like this to mimic running the application outside of a container:

`docker run --rm -d -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 <IMAGE_TAG>`

The networking of containers can get pretty involved, the [docs on links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) is a decent primer on the possible configurations.